# Should I always inherit from NSObject in Swift classes not to lose certain capabilities

Tags: swift

I am on beta 6, not sure if this is a bug or something I should be careful about in Swift language.

I have an array of `class B` objects declared in `class A`. Inside A, I have a function to see if a certain object exists in the array. Using `contains` function fails with a compiler error in below example unless I 
inherit NSObject in class B. So whats the issue here, should I always inherit from NSObject?

```
class B {
  ....
}

class A {
  var arr: Array<B> = Array<B>()

  func check(obj: B) -> Bool {
    return contains(arr, obj)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to be useable by *contains* your class must implement the protocol *Equatable*. When you inherit from NSObject, this is implemented for you. If you want to do it yourself you can do something like:

```
func == (lhs: B, rhs: B) -> Bool {
  return lhs === rhs
}

class B : Equatable {
}
```

See more about Equatable here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Equatable.html

Comment: Decided go with the identity operators rather than using the contains function; === and !==  Thanks for the tip